# Disable ui-router to some url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have some urls, like `/some_url_1/`, `/some_url_2/` and `/static_url/`.

In my app-config i defined ui-router states for urls `/some_url_1/` and `/some_url_2/`,  but url `/static_url/` must doing full reaload page as if i dont using angular.

Now, when on page `/some_url_1/` i click to `a[href="/static_url/"]` ui-router try to find state for this url, but cant find and page content stay as at `/some_url_1/`.

How i can disable `/static_url/` for ui-router and make full reload page to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this (It's not tested):

```
<a href="/url/whatever" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">Outside link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `target="_self"`

```
<a href="url/to/reload.html" target="_self">link</link>
```